# How to find the origin of variable in Drupal

Tags: 7

Maybe this a compound question, please bear with me: I need to find out why the meta tags are not being printed on the homepage of a theme. The problem is that in `html.tpl.php` I've got this line: `<?php print $head; ?>`.

In other pages, the meta tags are being printed ok, but not on the homepage. When I look at the `page--front.tpl.php` it doesn't include any header info or markup (only the markup from the menu downwards and I can't figure out:

1. Why the difference and;
2. Where is the `$head` being defined.

And yes, the content of the homepage does have tags added to it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should debug the code not in theme but in the module.

I assume you use the [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module. It adds all the metatags in [metatag_html_head_alter()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!metatag!metatag.module/function/metatag_html_head_alter/7).

Check what is your front page. If it is a View of a Panel, metatags are handled in a different way.

In the metatag module you [can specify separate tags](https://www.drupal.org/files/images/Meta%20tags%20%7C%20Drupal%207%20test%20site.png) for the front page - check this setting. It might override your content metatags.